# How to let users know that updates are not real time

Tags: mobile-web, time, response-time

I'm working on a food ordering mobile website. After ordering the meal, the preparation progress screen that aims to give users a rough estimate on what time their meal will be ready. Due to technical limitations, the time estimate won't update automatically. However if users refresh their browser, the time will be updated.

i'm faced with 2 choices

1. inform the user in words. that they need to refresh their browser
2. change the words of the time estimate to manage their expectations.

from these which is the better choice. and how should i convey the message, would appreciate examples. Or is there another way to overcome this?

[image: 1]

Comment: Not to get too far off topic, but I don't understand how updating the estimated time automatically could be impossible. Perhaps the constraints you're encountering at the moment have workarounds? Maybe we can provide an ideal UX solution here, and the folks at StackOverflow can assist with the technical limitations you're running into?

Comment: Is there any technical limitations on why you can't update in real time?

Comment: @AmeenAkbar Is it possible to provide details of the technical limitations?

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">`?

Comment: What limitations do you have on a *mobile* site that its impossible to not update the information in real time? You don't need to make new request, just interpolate on the client side (e.g. via JS).

Comment: @Polygnome Lack of skill or simply the inability to understand and solve something like this in real time (no matter if would be a simple meta refresh, API polling, web sockets, some background JS or whatever) is usually also considered a technical limitation when it comes to developing. Either way, the scope of this question is that real time updates are not possible, so there's no point in arguing about this. The question clearly asks for a non real time solution. Plus it's not even a technical question but one about UX, specifically on how to present certain static information to the user.

Comment: @NumLock: *Lack of skill or simply the inability to understand and solve something like this in real time is usually also considered a technical limitation when it comes to implementation or development. OP is asking about the UX, I get that, but the focus of your comment doesn't appear to address this.

Comment: @NumLock Not knowing something is not a *technical* limitation, it is (in most cases) a lack of training/knowledge. Challenging the assumption of the question is also part of Stack Exchange. People often have an XY-Problem. OP might *assume* they have a technical limitation that prohibits real-time updates, without this being actually true. Asking for clarification what those limitations actually are is exactly what comments are for.

Comment: just refresh it automatically with javascript? [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**Add the time of the last update**. That way users have a better understanding how old or new the information is. But it only works if you can use the users system clock to determine the shown time.

[image]

If you see that people don't think about refreshing the page, you can also provide a link for it:

[image]

Comment: For comparison, though not exactly the same thing, the company website I worked on recently has actual statistics on numbers of customers served and people available in the company to help out. These are values established in the database, and we simply provide a subtle grey text underneath saying when it was last updated (7AM, 11/03/2020) This serves the dual role of establishing that these stats aren't rounded off "marketing" stats, they're the real deal, and also tells the reader how accurate they are.
It works pretty well, though I'm not personally a fan of the exact text we use.

Comment: @jazZRo you could simply display "updated x min ago", if the system clock can't be used.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD i think if the value can not be updated due to technical limitations, the "x min ago" also can't be updated

Comment: @Christian right, I misinterpreted it as the app can't get the latest status from the server

Comment: Also with a circle like that, it kind of looks like a button and so the user will probably want to click/tap it. So OP might consider having something programmed to do ...something (refresh is perfect IMO).

Comment: I would not understand the last image. If it's currently 18:14, does it mean that 2 minutes ago the estimation was that it'll be ready 18:15 or 18:17? That is, does "last updated" refer to the text or the estimation?

Answer (score 98):

There is no reason to calculate this for the user unless you truly believe they cannot tell time.

"Your order will be ready at 18:12" should suffice; it does not matter how many minutes away that is.

This allows the user to make a quick mental note of when to check on their order instead of forcing them to think "Oh, it's 18:10 right now and 9 minutes ago it said I have 23 minutes left; or was that 12 minutes ago? Screw it I guess I'll just open the app again." Your current plan gives the end-user both a memory problem and a math problem all at once; don't do that.

Comment: Yes! There is a fashion at the moment to show everything as a relative time, even where this involves actively reducing the amount of information or increasing the burden on the user to interpret it. (While writing this comment, this answer went from "answered 16 hours ago" to "answered 17 hours ago"; I didn't spend an hour writing the comment!)

Comment: @PLL What would "updated at ..." signify. Does that tell you when the user loaded the page or is that more of a "Last status update from the server". Like at the one minute mark is it going to push out the time another 10 minutes because the order is not ready? If this is the food industry then it is atrociously short-sighted to think that the food staff is going to post real time delays to the app when they are behind on orders.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: of course I’m not suggesting the staff are manually updating the estimate. Most online delivery-order systems I’ve interacted with have several electronic check-in points — eg order submitted online; restaurant confirms order received; order given to delivery staff —and the estimate is automatically updated at each of these points.

Comment: @PLL OP makes no mention of a multi-step process so it's more of a "Come get your food at this time and it will probably be ready."

Comment: I like this approach generally, but I think the wording might need to change a bit — "Your order will be ready at 18:12" sounds quite definitive, so users may not feel the need to refresh for the latest estimate at all. I think in an area like food delivery, they'd need to be nudged more into getting fresh info as estimates are often pushed back

Comment: @anotherdave OP doesn't state that the time is ever updated. OP's literal issue is that they cannot program a simple countdown timer. So they're trying to solve it via UX instead of programming.

Comment: @IMSoP The fashion is to show enough information to make most users happy with very little clutter. It's easier for most people to think in time relative to their own, they only really care about how recent the information is and don't mind a slightly less precise final result. Anyone that actually cares about timestamps can typically hover (or tap) the text to get it.

Comment: @GammaGames That may be the intention of those that think about when to apply it, but it frequently isn't how relative dates are actually used in practice. I've seen multiple items on a page labelled "posted 1 day ago", with no information about which order they were posted in; or labels rounded to the nearest year hiding the fact that updates occur at the beginning of every month; or everything over a certain age labelled "a long time ago". As this answer says, "9 minutes ago, the estimate was 23 minutes" may _technically_ convey the information the user wants, but it isn't actually helpful.

Comment: @IMSoP I agree that using relative time in this case makes absolutely no sense, the practice is really only helpful when looking at something that is designed to be refreshed or updated regularly. "A long time ago" is a sin, but I don't really mind when something says "4 years ago" even if it was 4.25 years ago.

Comment: this is ALSO A FANTASTIC answer, bravo !

Answer (score 11):

Second choice is better to manage user expectations about estimated time.

You can create background process auto refresh every X second for update estimated time left, so user don't need to refresh the browser manually.

Make Optimistic UI with time display as countdown and give progress bar on circle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ashar, but as i've mentioned this isn't possible on due to technical limitations.

Comment: @AmeenAkbar What's wrong with a countdown timer? Store the amount of time needed (e.g. 3 mins = 180 seconds), then just update the countdown progress every second until 180 seconds have passed.

Is Javascript not an option?

Comment: @DavidWheatley: From a programming perspective you shouldn't use a counter. You should store the expected datetime and then recalculate using the current datetime each time you want to update the display. That said, the OP was clear that this is not an option. There may be other reasons not to do this than just "I don't know how".

Comment: @AmeenAkbar *Every other food ordering app* does this. It is not impossible. It is only impossible for you, for some reason.

Comment: In terms of expectation management I'd also point out that you should only display meaningful precision. In this case I wouldn't include seconds for sure, and I might not include minutes either unless to the minute delivery times are extremely reliable. Instead I might use generalizations like "soon", "in about 20 minutes", or "on time".

Comment: @AmeenAkbar by the way, as a software company, it is *your job* to choose technology which can do the things the app is supposed to do. You don't get to choose a technology which can't do what the customer wants, and then tell the customer they can't have the thing they want. The customer will find another company who *can* do it (because it's possible!)

Comment: @user253751 Like others, you're making a whole bunch of assumptions with no basis whatsoever. How do you know the OP is building the entire application and not contracted to make one screen? How do you know the contract didn't stipulate a particular technology because of some entirely irrational company policy that is nonetheless not negotiable? How do you even know that there are multiple companies involved, rather than an in-house development team?

Comment: @IMSoP Whatever the real reason is for the limitation, absolutely NONE of them are reasonable in this day and age. If it is a business constraint, then there is something seriously wrong with upper management. If it is a real "technical" limitation, then there's something really wrong with the technology in use. What are they using? IE4 on Windows 95? Auto page refresh has been possible 15 years ago, and that's a **crude** implementation. Modern JS can handle client-side countdown with no network usage..

Answer (score 3):

When reading the question, the Amazon parcel tracking app sprang to mind. That shows the location of the driver, but only updates every 30 seconds or so. In between time, it shows how long ago it was updated, incrementing every 10 seconds.

Something similar might suit your needs - as it gives a view of how current your information is but still updates at a frequency that makes sense for your users.

[image: amazon parcel tracking]